# change event not working for select2, how can I trigger the event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I've created the options using jquery:

```
<select name="models" class="form-control" id="models" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="0" class="select_model"> - </option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
var p = {
    event : 1
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'report/models',
    data: p,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
            $('.select_model').empty().append($('<option>', {
                value: data.models[i].model_id,
                text : data.models[i].model_name
            }));
        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $.alert({
            title: 'CAUTION!',
            content: "Theres an error: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText,
            type: 'red',
            icon: 'fa fa-warning',
        });
    }
});
```

then, when I call the event change, it just don't work:

```
$("#models").select2().change(function(){
    console.log('worked');
});
```

When I chose an option on the select, it not even log the message. What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure.. But it looks like you append options, via ajax, to the `.select_model` element... which is an option(!) I think the options should be appended to the `<select>` element... Inspect the rendered DOM.

Comment: Beyond that... I feel like you don't you instantiate `select2` with the ajax option, as in that [documentation](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)...

Comment: Thanks @LouysPatriceBessette , no need to use ajax option, the problem was the the empty() before the append(), when I removed that, it worked!